# Is there a way to make scribble border in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want element's border to be like pencil drawn in SwiftUI

For example, like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKras.png)

I've already tried strokeBorder(ImagePaint()), but when I use it, the outline of border becomes too clean, which I don't want.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Circle()
//            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//            .shadow(radius: 10)
//            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .strokeBorder(ImagePaint(image:Image("pencil3"), scale:0.3), lineWidth: 20)
//            .frame(width:100, height:100)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/na5iM.png)

Comment: The easiest is probably just doing it on Adobe Illustrator and using an SVG on the iOS side but I am sure you can make it with a path. Think of the scribble in terms of arcs, control points and start/end points. It would still likely be a cleaner look in iOS, I would just make the vector image unless you have a really good reason not to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to build up a circle using quad curves, each with a bit of random skew. When a few of these are laid over each other it gives quite a convincing appearance. The result can then be applied as an overlay to a view:

```swift
struct ScribbledCircle: View {

    struct ApproximateCircle: Shape {
        private let maxSkew = 0.04
        private var randomSkew: CGFloat {
            CGFloat.random(in: -maxSkew...maxSkew)
        }
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let w = rect.width
            let h = rect.height
            let xBegin = rect.minX + (w * randomSkew)
            let yBegin = rect.midY + (h * randomSkew)
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xBegin, y: yBegin))
            path.addQuadCurve(
                to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + (w * randomSkew), y: rect.minY + (h * randomSkew)),
                control: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + ((w / 2) * randomSkew), y: rect.minY + ((h / 2) * randomSkew))
            )
            path.addQuadCurve(
                to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + (w * randomSkew), y: rect.midY + (h * randomSkew)),
                control: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + ((w / 2) * randomSkew), y: rect.minY + ((h / 2) * randomSkew))
            )
            path.addQuadCurve(
                to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + (w * randomSkew), y: rect.maxY + (h * randomSkew)),
                control: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + ((w / 2) * randomSkew), y: rect.maxY + ((h / 2) * randomSkew))
            )
            path.addQuadCurve(
                to: CGPoint(x: xBegin, y: yBegin),
                control: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + ((w / 2) * randomSkew), y: rect.maxY + ((h / 2) * randomSkew))
            )
            path.closeSubpath()
            return path
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                ApproximateCircle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(i) * 15))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .overlay(
                ScribbledCircle()
            )
    }
}
```

[image: Scribbled circle]

As you might have noticed, a rotation effect is applied to the scribbed circles so that the points where the curves join are all offeset from each other. This works fine when the underlying shape is square. For non-square shapes, it works best to draw a scribbled circle in the same way and then stretch it to the required dimensions. The body of `ScribbledCircle` can be changed to the following to support all shapes in this way:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                    ApproximateCircle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(i) * 15))
                }
            }
            .frame(
                width: min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height),
                height: min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height)
            )
            .scaleEffect(
                x: proxy.size.width / min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height),
                y: proxy.size.height / min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height),
                anchor: .topLeading
            )
        }
    }
```

[image: SretchedCircle]

Comment: Then, is there a way to make a border something like this? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L3mTq32Nu-3Opvg34f_lU7-Hruk8H6WX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would be done in quite a different way. Probably best explored as a new question.